# ExtJs Ext.grid.Panel access model from column

Tags: javascript, extjs

In Ext.grid.Panel when user changes checkbox's state, I need to save the model that represents this row.

I have this code (very simplistically, because this component is very big):

```
Ext.define('Hts.Appointments.List.Grid', {
    extend        : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    initComponent : function() {
        this.store = /* Big initialization code for store */
        this.columns = [{
            header: Hts.Localization.APPOINTMENTS.HIGHLIGHT,
            dataIndex: 'highlighted',
            xtype: 'checkcolumn',
            flex: 1,
            listeners: {
                checkchange: function(column,rowIndex,checked) {
                       /* Here I need to access the model and save it */
                }
            },
            /* other columns */
        ]
    }
})
```

I hope I provided enough information (I'm very new in ExtJs).

Answer (score 0):

define your model with an id, using property 'idProperty'.

```
Ext.define('Model', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'idProp',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
    ]
});
```

you can get the model and save it with:

```
listeners: {
                checkchange: function(column,rowIndex,checked) {
                       var model = Ext.ModelManager.getModel('idProp'); // access
                       model.save(); //save
                }
            },
```

Comment: Unfortuanally i use version 3.* and there is no such property "idProp". And also I need to save only one row (where was checkbox), and not all the data in the table.

Comment: ah I'm sorry, my bad :) I only work with 4.* so I have no clue of 3.*... I hope someone will help u soon! good luck